# How can I print the intermediate variables in the loss function in TensorFlow and Keras?

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, keras

I'm writing a custom objective to train a Keras (with TensorFlow backend) model but I need to debug some intermediate computation. For simplicity, let's say I have:

```
def custom_loss(y_pred, y_true):
    diff = y_pred - y_true
    return K.square(diff)
```

I could not find an easy way to access, for example, the intermediate variable diff or its shape during training. In this simple example, I know that I could return diff to print its values, but my actual loss is more complex and I can't return intermediate values without getting compiling errors.

Is there an easy way to debug intermediate variables in Keras?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not something that is solved in Keras as far as I know, so you have to resort to backend-specific functionality. Both [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/printing.html) and [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/debugging_operations) have `Print` nodes that are identity nodes (i.e., they return the input node) and have the side-effect of printing the input (or some tensor of the input).

Example for Theano:

```
diff = y_pred - y_true
diff = theano.printing.Print('shape of diff', attrs=['shape'])(diff)
return K.square(diff)
```

Example for TensorFlow:

```
diff = y_pred - y_true
diff = tf.Print(diff, [tf.shape(diff)])
return K.square(diff)
```

Note that this only works for intermediate values. Keras expects tensors that are passed to other layers to have specific attributes such as `_keras_shape`. Values processed by the backend, i.e. through `Print`, usually do not have that attribute. To solve this, you can wrap debug statements in a [`Lambda`](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer for example.

Comment: To add to @nemo, Keras has these backend printing functions extended into keras through `K.print_tensor()` https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/theano_backend.py#L934 & https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L1896. I haven't tried using the `print_tensor()` function but as @nemo noted you have to use it with `Lambda` layer

Comment: Oh yes, forgot that this existed. But it does not help you if you want something different than the complete string representation of the tensor, e.g. the shape.

Comment: Thanks, but both tf.Print and K.print_tensor do not seem to print anything by themselves and if I wrap them with the stdout python print, i.e. print(tf.Print(diff, [tf.shape(diff)])) it is executed only once during the model compile phase and not during the run phase (during training)

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I did not assign the output of the print to another operation preventing it from being evaluated during the graph evaluation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In TensorFlow 2, you can now add IDE breakpoints in the TensorFlow Keras models/layers/losses, including when using the fit, evaluate, and predict methods. However, you must add `model.run_eagerly = True` **after** calling `model.compile()` for the values of the tensor to be available in the debugger at the breakpoint. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def custom_loss(y_pred, y_true):
    diff = y_pred - y_true
    return tf.keras.backend.square(diff)  # Breakpoint in IDE here. =====

class SimpleModel(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense0 = Dense(2)
        self.dense1 = Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        z = self.dense0(inputs)
        z = self.dense1(z)
        return z

x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=tf.float32)
y = tf.convert_to_tensor([0, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

model0 = SimpleModel()
model0.run_eagerly = True
model0.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=custom_loss)
y0 = model0.fit(x, y, epochs=1)  # Values of diff *not* shown at breakpoint. =====

model1 = SimpleModel()
model1.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=custom_loss)
model1.run_eagerly = True
y1 = model1.fit(x, y, epochs=1)  # Values of diff shown at breakpoint. =====
```

This also works for debugging the outputs of intermediate network layers (for example, adding the breakpoint in the `call` of the SimpleModel).

*Note: this was tested in TensorFlow `2.0.0-rc0`.*

Comment: Can something similar also be done for displaying the activations of layers of the network (and not just the value of the loss or any intermediate value for the loss)?

Comment: @nbro, Yes. However, you need to write the model with an explicit call function. See my related answer about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57729876/1191087

Comment: But I don't want to subclass `Model`. I would like to use the debugger with built-in layers.

Comment: @nbro, the `Dense` layers are built-in layers. Are you using the `Sequential` class currently? The only (major) difference between `Sequential` and `Model` is that `Sequential` sets up the `call` method for you. If you're talking about something else, I may need a bit more details.

Comment: I currently using the functional API (but I may switch back to the sequential API later). Anyway, I would just like to print the values of the outputs of the intermediate layers (or any other stuff, like the `losses` property of the model) at the beginning (or end) of each epoch. However, I cannot use `tf.print`. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35949. If I use Python's `print`, it doesn't print the actual value of the tensors, but just the symbolic representations. Note that I am using TF 2.0.

Comment: @nbro, I see. The functional API is the same as subclassing the model, just written in a slight different way. See the [first two examples here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=stable), where they create the same model using both the functional API and the subclassing method. I believe you will need to use the subclassing method if you want to use breakpoints. Otherwise, you do not have access to the `call` method to add your breakpoints to.

Comment: I have simply copy pasted this example in visual studio code, I am using tensorflow 2.1.0 changes to get it run y1 = model1.fit(x, y, epochs=1,steps_per_epoch=1)  # Values of diff shown at breakpoint. =====, inspite of that I don't know how to get the value of diff at the breakpoint, tf.print(diff,sys.stdout) doesn't print any values

Comment: @abacusreaser, do you have a breakpoint and are running the code in debug mode within VSCode? Note that an IDE breakpoint is part of the editor (e.g. part of VSCode) and does not appear in the code itself. You need to add it separately. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging

Comment: i use Spider IDE, i copied and paste your code and put on a checkpoint (red bullet)  on the specified line of code and ran the code. however, i didn't get any debugged value. please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In TensorFlow 2.0, you can use [`tf.print`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print?version=stable) and print anything inside the definition of your loss function. You can also do something like `tf.print("my_intermediate_tensor =", my_intermediate_tensor)`, i.e. with a message, similar to Python's `print`. However, you may need to decorate your loss function with [`@tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function?version=stable) to actually see the results of the `tf.print`.

Comment: Can you provide a detailed code piece, most are newbies and are asking questions here because of poor examples available on internet