# Print layer outputs in Keras during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am new to Keras. How can I print the outputs of a layer, both intermediate or final, during the training phase?

I am trying to debug my neural network and wanted to know how the layers behave during training. To do so I am trying to exact input and output of a layer during training, for every step.

The FAQ (https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) has a method to extract output of intermediate layer for building another model but that is not what I want. I don't need to use the intermediate layer output as input to other layer, I just need to print their values out and perhaps graph/chart/visualize it.

I am using Keras 2.1.4

Comment: This doesn't allow you to drill down into individual layers, but if your underlying interest is figuring out what the model is doing, check out https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out =]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have found an answer myself, although not strictly accomplished by Keras.

Basically, to access layer output during training, one needs to modify the computation graph by adding a print node.

A more detailed description can be found in this StackOverflow question:
[How can I print the intermediate variables in the loss function in TensorFlow and Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42233963/3924118)

I will quote an example here, say you would like to have your loss get printed per step, you need to set your custom loss function as:

for Theano backend:

```
diff = y_pred - y_true
diff = theano.printing.Print('shape of diff', attrs=['shape'])(diff)
return K.square(diff)
```

for Tensorflow backend:

```
diff = y_pred - y_true
diff = tf.Print(diff, [tf.shape(diff)])
return K.square(diff)
```

Outputs of other layers can be accessed similarly.

There is also a nice vice tutorial about using `tf.Print()` from Google
[Using tf.Print() in TensorFlow](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-tf-print-in-tensorflow-aa26e1cff11e)

Comment: `tf.Print` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more info on each neuron, you need to use the following to get their bias and weights.

```
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
```

0 index defines weights and 1 defines the bias.

You can also get per layer too,

```
for layer in model.layers:
    weights = layer.get_weights() # list of numpy arrays
```

After each training, if you can access each layer with its dimension and obtain the weights and bias to a numpy array, you should be able to visualize how the neuron after each training.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, can I get the the layer puts per step in this way or is it accessible only after a complete training?

Comment: You can access the layer details at any point, prior or during training or after completion of training.

Comment: I am really sorry but I haven't got time to integrate your code yet into my project yet, because the solution I found is working quite well.

I believe your suggestion might work better because it is done using keras library instead of directly the backend.

Do you mind giving an example of how I can use it to print layer output per step during training?

Then I can quickly test and mark your answer correct.